# How to dynamically add N dygraphs to page|table

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am using Flask (Jinja2) to serve up pages containing dygraph. 
Everything works fine but I am struggling to find a way to add N graphs to a page since dygraphs expect a known Div to use and I don't know if my page will be displaying 2 graphs or 10

looking for way to do this:

```
<table>
   {% for key, value in sitedata %}
     <tr> <td>
     <!--  new graph generated from  data in  'value' goes here -->
     </td></tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Thanks

Bill

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and here's how for anyone else wanting to do this.

there are two issues that needed to be solved.

1. the div  - actually pretty easy since it can be constructed in Jinja2 just like anything else. Just set ID based on the key to make sure it is unique.
2. Creating the dyngraph - Has to be called in the client so I did this by wrapping all the dyngraph stuff into a JS function and then used jinja2 to add an img element to my new table row which has a bad src= and specifies my dyngraph function with correct parameters in its onerror=.
   Rough pseudocode below:

   {% for key, value in sitedata %}
    
   {% set divid = 'key' + key %}
   {% set graphdata = value.data %}
    


   {% endfor %}